# Откуда взялись f и g, что это такое и как работает?

Tags: javascript

На странице [учебника JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods) я увидел такой пример:

```js
var user = { firstName: "Вася" };
var admin = { firstName: "Админ" };

function func() {
  alert( this.firstName );
}

user.f = func;
admin.g = func;

// this равен объекту перед точкой:
user.f(); // Вася
admin.g(); // Админ
admin['g'](); // Админ (не важно, доступ к объекту через точку или квадратные скобки)
```

Никак не пойму откуда взялись f и g в объектах user и admin. Как это называется и как работает?

```js
user.f = func;
admin.g = func;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты в Javascript по умолчанию позволяют расширять себя, добавляя методы и поля.

Поэтому при присваивании значения, в случае отсутствия, соответствующее поле будет добавлено непосредственно в объект.

---

```js
var user = {};
console.log(user.hasOwnProperty('f'));
user.f = "a";
console.log(user.hasOwnProperty('f'));
```

---

Однако автоматическое добавление не сработает в случае

1. примитивных значений: строк, чисел и т.д.,
2. объектов к котором применен метод [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)
3. объектов к котором применен метод [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)
4. объектов к котором применен метод [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```js
var user1 = {},
  user2 = {},
  user3 = {},
  user4 = {};

console.log(user1.hasOwnProperty('a'), user2.hasOwnProperty('a'), user3.hasOwnProperty('a'), user4.hasOwnProperty('a'));

Object.preventExtensions(user2);
Object.seal(user3);
Object.freeze(user4);

user1.a = user2.a = user3.a = user4.a = 10;

console.log(user1.hasOwnProperty('a'), user2.hasOwnProperty('a'), user3.hasOwnProperty('a'), user4.hasOwnProperty('a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё довольно просто, стоит только вывести объект в консоль:

```js
var user = { firstName: "Вася" };
var admin = { firstName: "Админ" };

function func() {
  alert( this.firstName );
}

user.f = func;
admin.g = func;

console.log(user);
```

Здесь мы видим что у объекта появилось новое свойство-функция, которая была присвоена кодом `user.f = func;`. Вы можете также присвоить и обычное свойство объекту:

```js
var user = { firstName: "Вася" };
var admin = { firstName: "Админ" };

user.f = "a";
admin.g = 123;

console.log(user);
console.log(admin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так Вы же сами добавляете свойства `f` и `g` объектам. Их значениями является ссылка на функцию `func` - при вызове `this` берёт свойства у объекта на который ссылается, следовательно в первом случае `this.firstName` будет равно "Вася", а во втором - "Админ".